# SQLite JSON_EXTRACT All values of 1 object in an array

Tags: arrays, json, sqlite, json-extract

I have a column containing JSON arrays. The arrays are like this (table users, column user_info):

```
[
 {"email":"xyz@hotmail.com","user_key":"987654","name":"John Paul"},
 {"email":"abc@hotmail.com","user_key":"123456","name":"Tom Sawyer"},
 {"email":"1234@msn.com","user_key":"887645","name":"Bart Simpson"}
]
```

Some have 3 objects in each array, some have 20, some in between. I want to pull each "name" value from the arrays. So with the above example I want my query results to show:

```
John Paul
Tom Sawyer
Bart Simpson
```

I can do that with:

```
SELECT json_extract(users.user_info, '$[0]."name"', $[1]."name"', $[2]."name"')
FROM users
```

However, if I want to select ALL of them, no matter the length in each row of that column, how would I go about that so I don't have to list out each object number of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the *table-valued function* [`json_each()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jeach):

```
SELECT json_extract(json_each.value, '$.name') name
FROM users u, json_each(user_info)
```

If you want all the names of each row in a comma separated list you could use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(json_extract(json_each.value, '$.name')) name
FROM users u, json_each(user_info)
GROUP BY u.thread_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=78279a30c963c45db262435a1eb5fa8f).

Comment: Is there a way to make all 3 names to appear in one row? Instead of it being:

1. John Paul
2. Tom Sawyer
3. Bart Simpson

Can I get it to be:
1. John Paul Tom Sawyer Bart Simpson

Comment: @SnakeDoc65 is there another column like a primary key `id` in the table?

Comment: @SnakeDoc65 see my 2nd query.

Comment: This worked for me trying to do a `IN` subquery:

`SELECT * FROM videos WHERE _id in (SELECT json_each.value FROM playlists, json_each(videos, '$.videos') where youtube_id = 'XXX');`